# Почему не передаются параметры при создание меток через массив GeoObjectCollection ? yandex-maps-api

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет, помогите с пожалуйста с вопросом. Сильно не ругайте, сегодня первый день как пишу код .

Сначала пытался добавить параметры и геопозицию из массива, через часы тестов так и не получилось, попробовал добавить на "полуавтомате" (код ниже)

Пытаюсь понять как написать код, что бы через массив я мог добавлять  параметры точки, в том числе id, пробовал и так, и сяк, не выходит .

Через обход массива сами точки добавляются, но без параметров =(

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.755773, 37.617761],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        RiderCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({},{})
    // массив адресов
    massiveAdress = [[55.73, 37.75], [55.81, 37.75], [55.73, 37.65], [55.81, 37.65]]
        // пытаюсь через обход массива добавить точки с описанием  
    for (var i = 0, l = massiveAdress.length; i < l; i++) {
        RiderCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(massiveAdress[i]),{
            id: 'id_1',
            balloonContent: 'содержимое балуна',
            hintContent: 'содержимое всплывающей подсказки'
        });

    }
    // пробую добавить единичным способом, все ок.
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.7, 37.5], {
        id: 'id_1',
        balloonContent: 'содержимое балуна',
        hintContent: 'содержимое всплывающей подсказки'
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon'
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(RiderCollection);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закрывающая скобка не там. Надо так:

```
        RiderCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(massiveAdress[i],{
            id: 'id_1',
            balloonContent: 'содержимое балуна',
            hintContent: 'содержимое всплывающей подсказки'
        }));
```

Comment: ух еееее. Сколько потраченный часов, а все из за одной скобки. Спасибо за подсказку!